# Does std::thread().join() really make threads run concurrently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I need a piece of code that sets up a couple of threads to run concurrently, and after they are all finished, print something to inform the user. Here's the code(using c++11's library on Windows):

```
void func1(){
     int j = 0;
     while(j<=100000) j++;
}

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::thread t(func1);
        printf("releasing thread %d\n",i);
        t.join();
    printf("all threads finished\n");
    }   
}
```

I thought this will make all the threads run concurrently, but turns out it only runs one thread at a time, wait until it finishes, and execute the next one. 
Outout:

```
releasing thread 0
releasing thread 1
releasing thread 2
releasing thread 3
releasing thread 4
all threads finished
```

In that case, what's the point of having join() if it doesn't separate the threads? What should I do to achieve what I described?

Comment: [RTFM](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join).

Comment: Why the hell would a method called join separate threads

Comment: @aaronman because according to this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/ join makes threads execute separately. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: use two for-loops and a vector of threads. I think you'll be more pleased with the outcome. All you're doing in the posted code is starting a thread, then waiting for it to finish, before starting the *next* thread. IOW, you have a very expensive function call.

Comment: `all threads finished` should appear 5 times in the output window. you should correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see this example. You have to start all the threads, then 'join' them later.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, without a `join()` call the threads will run concurrently, but with no built-in data race protection, which is a problem you will need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The displayed code does not generate the displayed output.  You have a misplaced `{`.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void func1(int i){
  int j = 0;
  while(j<=100000) j++;
  std::cout << "thread " << i << " finished\n";
}

int main(){
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  try {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      threads.push_back(std::thread(func1, i));
    }   
  } catch (...) {
  }
  for( std::thread& t : threads ) {
    t.join();
  }
  std::cout << "all threads finished\n";
}
```

What `join` does is makes your main thread wait until the `thread` in question is finished.

Generally you should avoid using `std::thread` in the raw, because failure to `join` or `detach` will cause your program to terminate.  Hence the ridiculously aggressive `try`/`catch` block above: it is far from sufficient.

`std::async` is a bit easier to use:

```
void func1(int i){
  int j = 0;
  while(j<=100000) j++;
  std::cout << "thread " << i << " finished\n";
}

int main(){
  std::vector<std::future> threads;
  try {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      threads.push_back(std::async(func1, i));
    }   
  }
  for( std::future& f : threads ) {
    f.wait();
  }
  std::cout << "all threads finished\n";
}
```

in general.  Note, however, that the MSVC 2012 and 2013 `std::async` is not standards compliant and the above code remains unsafe for it as well.

You should, in general, wrap your threading primitives in your own RAII wrappers for anything besides trivial use.